# How can I convert the following JSON to a JSON that can be used by JSTree

Tags: jquery, json, jstree

I want to use JS to display a jstree described by the json below. But, I am not sure how to use jstree to do this?

JQUERY:

```
$("#jstree1").jstree({
    'core': {
        'data': {
            "url": ajaxUrl,
            "dataType": "json", // needed only if you do not supply JSON headers   
        }
    }
});
```

JSON:

```
{

    "parent": {

        "item": ["cs", "ls"]

    },

    "cs": {

        "item": ["cs_1"]

    },

    "ls": {

        "item": ["ls_1"]

    },

    "cs_1": {

        "item": ["cs_1_1"]

    },

    "cs_1_1": {

        "item": ["cs_1_1_1", "cs_1_1_2"]

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a flat format here, so you need to specify parent id's for all elements with root element(s) having `#` as parent. See correct JSON below.

Also check demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/b1m4d1rt/).

```
[
  { "id": "parent", "text": "parent", "parent": "#" },
  { "id": "cs", "text": "cs", "parent": "parent" },
  { "id": "ls", "text": "ls", "parent": "parent" },
  { "id": "cs_1", "text": "cs_1", "parent": "cs" },
  { "id": "cs_1_1", "text": "cs_1_1", "parent": "cs_1" },
  { "id": "cs_1_1_1", "text": "cs_1_1_1", "parent": "cs_1_1" },
  { "id": "cs_1_1_2", "text": "cs_1_1_2", "parent": "cs_1_1" }
]
```